# fetching document from mongodb-nodejs driver using dates

Tags: node.js, mongodb, postman

Hi i am trying to fetch documents from mongodb specifically for D-7th day 
Example:If today is "*Wednesday*" then i want to fetch documents of last "*Wednesday*" only

I am getting the date from the front-end,the

Date format in mongodb: `2020-01-15T09:02:48.375+00:00`
Date format from postman:"2020-01-15" which i am converting in nodejs into dateObject .after consoling dateObject Dates looks like this: 2020-01-15T00:00:00.000Z

**nodejs query**

```
const { previousDay,vendorId } = req.body;
      console.log(previousDay);
      let date = new Date(previousDay);
      console.log(date);
     const vendorOrder = await Order.find(
          {orderCreatedBy: vendorId,orderCreatedOn: date});
     return res.status(200).json({
         vendorOrder
        });
      } catch (error) {
        res.send(error);
      }
    };
```

**POSTMAN Req.body**

```
{ "previousDay":"2020-01-15"}
```

**POSTMAN Response**
it returns empty Array

```
[]
```

**Mongodb collection**

```
_id:5e26be38c13b7149d0a95111
isApproved:false
vendorOrder:[]
frequency:"WE"
orderCreatedBy:5e25550a3405363bc4bf86c1
submittedTo:5e2555363405363bc4bf86c2
dealerOrder:[]
orderCreatedOn:2020-01-15T09:02:48.375+00:00
__v:0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now there is problem matching the date because mongodb will match the full date including the timeStamp so at the time of saving the document set the constant time stamp along with date . 


Let us understand using the example ..

When you save the document , at that time set the value of `orderCreatedOn` as below snippet , 
**Edited**

```
exports.createOrder = async (req, res, next) => { 
    req.body['orderCreatedOn'] = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0] + "T18:30:00.000Z";
    const order = new Order({ ...req.body, }); 
    try { 
        await order.save(); 
        res.status(201).json({ message: "Order created successfully!", order: order, orderId: order._id }); 
    } 
    catch (e) { 
        res.send(e); 
    } 
};
```

As a result your date in data base will be stored like , `2020-01-15T18:30:00.000Z`

So now when you find the date of before 7 days , then add the below snippet in in your find controller.

```
    var someDate = new Date();
    var numberOfDaysToSubtract = -7; //this refers to date of seven days before
    someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate() + numberOfDaysToSubtract);
    console.log("Date of seven days before ===>" , someDate);
    var date = someDate.toISOString().split("T")[0] + "T18:30:00.000Z";
    date = new Date(date);
    //And the rest code is same. 
    console.log(" =======+++> ", new Date(date));
```

Hope you got the solution.

Comment: thanks your code cleared a lot of things except one req.body['orderCreatedOn'] but orderCreatedOn is generating date from my schema how will i get that from req.body

Comment: replace req.body['orderCreatedOn'] with req.body['previousDay']  as you are sending previousDay in req.body. @sachin

Comment: orderCreatedOn: {
   
      type: Date,
   
      default: Date.now
    },

Comment: okk sorry i misunderstood you. @sachin . You were asking at the time when you save document

Comment: req.body['orderCreatedOn'] . This will create a key in req.body. You have to not worry about this. @sachin

Comment: exports.createOrder = async (req, res, next) => {
   const order = new Order({
    ...req.body,
  });
  try {
    await order.save();
    res.status(201).json({
      message: "Order created successfully!",
      order: order,
      orderId: order._id
    });
  } catch (e) {
    res.send(e);
  }
};....this is the way i am saving the orders now how will i save the orderCreatedOn according to your solution if can have a look at my code

Comment: i have got the solution its working now thanks@ Pushprajsinh

Comment: Happy to help you . Happy coding :) .

Comment: Please upvote the answer if you are eligible for it . @sachin

Answer (score 1):

**MongoDB Schema:**

```
orderCreatedOn: {
      type: Date,
      default: new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0] + "T18:30:00.000Z"
    },
```

Nodejs Controller : refer @ Pushprajsinh Chudasama answer